# Train TFRobertaModel in PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I want to create a model in PyTorch, where first I use ROBERTA to create the contexualized representation of the input sentence, and then I want to use it and some more inputs (which aren't words) for a prediction task.

That's why I want to use the basic TFRobertaModel to get the contexualized embeddings, but I would also like to train it together with my model (using GPU).

This is my model definition:

```
roberta_model = TFRobertaModel.from_pretrained("roberta-base")
```

However, `roberta_model` doesn't have `cuda()` or `train()` or `eval()` methods (but `roberta_model.trainable == True`).

How can I train it? What am I missing?

Thanks!